# handling terminal input responses from a script to add data to a database

Tags: python, mysql

I'm doing a script to add many dotSql files that I have to MySQL. So far, I have the path of each file ready, the name of each file ready, the join between those too ready, but im struggling at handling the command, I must execute to add them to MySQL.

```
system("mysql -u root -p database < "+ files[i] +"")
```

This is running inside a for, the problem is that I have to input the password each loop, is there a way to automatically do the input which is the same every time? It's the password...

Answer (score 0):

figured out by looking the mysql documentation, that you can actually do this:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword
```

and it doesnt ask for the password anymore, if every one still knows how to handle the responding input of the past command please let me know, it would be interesting to know how handle it from python